# MySQL connection not working from within Perl CGI script

Tags: perl, apache, tomcat, cgi, dbi

I can easily connect to a remote MySQL server using the DBI module in my Perl scripts. However, when I try to use the same connection settings/properties from within a CGI script, the connection fails.

There are no helpful errors/warnings being logged either in the apache error log, or the browser, in spite of using

```
use CGI::Carp qw(warningsToBrowser fatalsToBrowser);
```

Strangely, the exact same script works fine when executed from the terminal. I also tried connecting the CGI script to the MySQL server on localhost, but without any success.

On the other hand, phpMyAdmin works great on the machine.

I'm using CentOS Release 5.8. I'm suspecting it is a system/priveleges issue with the apache user or anywhere else on the OS, but have hit a dead end.

Any pointers would be much appreciated!

Thanks a lot.

*Edit: I'm using the following connection string*

```
$dbh = DBI->connect($ds, $uname, $pwd,{RaiseError => 1 }) or die "$DBI::errstr Could not connect: $!<br>";
```

Comment: There are always error messages. You're either not accessing them correctly, or ignoring them.

Comment: Try executing the same script on the terminal, but first change to the Apache user.  `sudo -u <apache user> <your script>`.  If it fails, that will be much easier to debug.  Also, if there are no errors or warnings, how do you know the connection failed?

Comment: @LenJaffe - Well, I'm getting the following error message:

`Software error:

    DBI connect('$dbname:$host:$port','$username',...) failed: Can't connect to MySQL server on '$host' (13) at /var/www/cgi-bin/crm/$scriptname.cgi line 24`

Not sure what to make out of that. Thanks

Comment: @Schwern - Thanks for the hint! I ran the script from terminal as apache user, and it executes without any error! Even more confusion now. What could be wrong?

Comment: Did it really have `$dbname:$host:$port` and `$username` in the error string?  Try printing out `$ds`, `$uname` and `$pwd`.  I think they don't contain what you think they contain.  I think you have a single quote somewhere you should have a double.

Comment: @Schwern - Oh of course not! It prints out the values of the variables that have been set in the script before. I just replaced the actual values with variables for posting here. Though they are printed out within single quotes on the browser. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed it. In case anyone not too familiar with Linux administration faces similar issue, here's what had happened. The security system 'selinux' on my CentOS machine was prohibiting the httpd to establish network connection to the remote MySQL server. It had to be explicitly enabled with the following command

```
setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect=1
```

One can read more about selinux over here:

http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/SELinux

Answer (score 0):

Check what users you have set up in MySQL.  If you're trying to connect across a network connection, you could have a problem with the host association for the user.

Try:
    select host,user from mysql.user

Comment: Thanks Nicole. The MySQL user I'm using to connect seems to be having the appropriate privileges. Value for Select_Priv column is 'Y' for 2 entries for the username for Host 'localhost' and '%' respectively. 

In any case, as I mentioned before, I can connect to the MySQL from the same host, but from terminal. Problem occurs only while calling the script from browser. Executing the script from terminal with apache user works fine too!