# DBI->connect working when executed in terminal but not when executed from browser

Tags: mysql, perl, localhost, cgi, dbi

I am writing a CGI program that prints a database query result in the browser. The script looks like this

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use DBI;

print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";

my $driver   = "mysql";
my $database = "DBname";
my $ip       = "127.0.0.1";
my $db       = "DBI:$driver:DBNAME:$ip:database=$database";
my $username = "user";
my $password = "pass";

print "Connecting ...";

my $connection = DBI->connect($db, $username, $password)
    or print "Couldn't connect to database: " . DBI->errstr . "\n\n";

print "Successful connection\n";

my $query = $connection->prepare("SELECT id FROM table");

$query->execute() or die $DBI::errstr;

while ( my @row = $query->fetchrow_array() ) {
    my ($id) = @row;
    print "ID = $id \n";
}

$query->finish();
```

Well, my problem is that when I run it from terminal using

```
perl test.cgi
```

it works fine, and I get the print results properly. The CGI script is located in `/Library/Webserver/CGI-Executables/` and it is configured by default /cgi-bin/ in `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf`

If I execute it via the web browser, I just get the first print `Connecting` and nothing else, not even the `or print` from `DBI->connect`. I have been trying to realize what the error is, but I am unable to get a useful solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12408795/mysql-connection-not-working-from-within-perl-cgi-script?rq=1

Comment: @Tanktalus no it's not the same error... I am using Mac OS High Sierra and Apache2 as server. Still don't know what the problem is, thank you anyways!

Comment: Have you checked the error log if something was logged there?

Comment: Is the web server using the same copy of perl as you use from the command line? Is it possible that there is no `DBD::mysql` installed for the server? I suggest that you add `use DBD::mysql` to the top of the file. If the driver is unavailable then your code will die immediately instead of waiting until `DBI` tries to autoload it.

Comment: @Borodin The error_log file from Apache displays 4 errors, all related to DBD::mysql, so I guess it is because I have the module in my terminal but not configured for Apache. I tried use DBD::mysql as you said but then I get 500 Internal Server Error and the error_log shows `AH01215: Can't locate DBD/mysql.pm in @INC (you may need to install the DBD::mysql module)`. Don't know what else to try, but thank you for your help!

Comment: By the way, the content type should be `text/plain`, not `text/html`: you're not generating HTML.

Answer (score 0):

From your final comment it is as I suspected: the perl that the server is using simply doesn't have `DBD::mysql` installed, whereas your command-line perl does

Simply get that driver module installed on the server and all should be well

Note that is doesn't need to be "configured for Apache", it is simply that the copy of perl that is used by the CGI code doesn't have that module

By the way, the content type should be `text/plain`, not `text/html`: you're not generating HTML

Comment: ok thank you for your answer I will try it now! Last thing is, how do I install the driver in Perl? (This is a university project and I have never used Perl, so I think it is easy to update my Perl version with the new modules, but sorry for my misunderstanding...) Thank you!!!

Comment: I don't know. As I said, you appear to be running different instances of perl on your command line and on the server. You need to get to a place where the latter is the default, and issue `cpan DBD::mysql`, but I have no idea if that is even possible because I have no knowledge of your system structure.